# Intune Distribution of an Android APK

Tags: android, apk, intune, intunemam

We have an issue with the distribution of an APK with Microsoft Intune (Android).

The original APK works fine.

For Microsoft Intune Distribution we need to wrap it with a Microsoft Powershell script:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-wrapper-prepare-android
- https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/intune-app-wrapping-tool-android

Microsoft script wrapped the original APK in a new one; next we need to zipalign and resign it with apk signer (as the script's output also say).

The wrapped APK installs correctly on enrolled devices but fails to open (blank screen). You can't even see the initial page.

Analyzing the LogCat we noticed that after initial checks there are 3 errors repeating many times till a fatal exception (maximum call stack exceeded).

The three errors (MAMTrace) are:

1. Already tracing scenario ONLINE_FIRST_HOOKED_ACTIVITY_STARTUP
2. Tried to start tracing for sub-operation onCreate common for scenario ONLINE_FIRST_HOOKED_ACTIVITY_STARTUP that is already being traced.
3. Tried to start tracing for sub-operation onMAMCreate for scenario ONLINE_FIRST_HOOKED_ACTIVITY_STARTUP that is already being traced.

After many loops...

- FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- Process: com.xxx, PID: 21139
- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx/sap.mdkclient.MDKAndroidActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
- RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Any idea experts?

The wrapped APK installs correctly on enrolled devices but fails to open (blank screen). You can't even see the initial page. We're expecting the application to start.

Comment: The errors in LogCat seem to suggest that the Intune wrapper is trying to trace the same operation multiple times, which might be triggering the recursive loop.
Try to gradually remove parts of your code and re-wrap the app until you identify the part of the code that's causing the issue.

Also, check your code for any possible recursive calls in onCreate or other lifecycle methods that might be interacting negatively with the Intune wrapping tool.

You can  contact Microsoft Support directly https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/intune-app-wrapping-tool-android/issues